# Not able to enable debug debugger for laravel in PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpstorm, xdebug

My XAMPP installation in `php.ini` file

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.idekey=PHPStorm
```

I done all setting in PhpStorm. But i am not able to start debugger my link is like that

http://localhost/aniCare/admin/login?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=13773

I put breakpoint on my function login. I m getting this Error:

[image]

My xdebug information:

[image]

Comment: **1)** When showing your xdebug settings then show ALL of them not only few (that's regarding your last screenshot) . **2)** You have `xdebug.remote_enable = 0` in your php.ini -- now go and check what that option does and what the correct value should be -- https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings

Comment: @LazyOne yes i m change that value by 1 . again i get same error

Comment: Please prove it -- post a full screenshot of xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output (and not only top of it like you did in the actual question). P.S. And not `i m` but `I'm` or `I am`

Comment: @LazyOne - yes i upload whole xdebug setting

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows that you still have `remote_enable = Off` (same as `0`). 1) Have you restarted your Apache after making changes in `php.ini` 2) If you did -- what php.ini file you were editing (provide me full path) as well as header of the `phpinfo()` output

Comment: @LazyOne - Actually i  m not refresh that web page which i send i edit my phpinfo page

Comment: Close all existing debug sessions (so that there is no Debug panel) and try debugging again. If still the same -- collect xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug attempt: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: BTW -- have you seen the official manuals/videos? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: Yes I do my all possibles but its not working anfd i show many tutorials but its not working @LazyOne

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109105/discussion-between-ekta-singh-and-lazyone).